How can I write a hexadecimal viewer in C?
I'm working on a code for a homework. Our teacher gave us this example. We gotta write a code about a hexadecimal viewer. This one must write down lines, edit, map characters and edit.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

/* Variable global para mejor legibilidad */
int fd; // Archivo a leer


char *hazLinea(char *base, int dir) {
    char linea[100]; // La linea es mas pequeña
    int o=0;
    // Muestra 16 caracteres por cada linea
    o += sprintf(linea,"%08x ",dir); // offset en hexadecimal
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        unsigned char a,b,c,d;
        a = base[dir+4*i+0];
        b = base[dir+4*i+1];
        c = base[dir+4*i+2];
        d = base[dir+4*i+3];
        o += sprintf(&linea[o],"%02x %02x %02x %02x ", a, b, c, d);
    }
    for(int i=0; i < 16; i++) {
        if (isprint(base[dir+i])) {
            o += sprintf(&linea[o],"%c",base[dir+i]);
        }
        else {
            o += sprintf(&linea[o],".");
        }
    }
    sprintf(&linea[o],"\n");

    return(strdup(linea));
}

char *mapFile(char *filePath) {
    /* Abre archivo */
    fd = open(filePath, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("Error abriendo el archivo");
        return(NULL);
    }

    /* Mapea archivo */
    struct stat st;
    fstat(fd,&st);
    long fs = st.st_size;

    char *map = mmap(0, fs, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mapeando el archivo");
        return(NULL);
    }

  return map;
}

int leeChar() {
  int chars[5];
  int ch,i=0;
  nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
  while((ch = getch()) == ERR); /* Espera activa */
  ungetch(ch);
  while((ch = getch()) != ERR) {
    chars[i++]=ch;
  }
  /* convierte a numero con todo lo leido */
  int res=0;
  for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
    res <<=8;
    res |= chars[j];
  }
  return res;
}


int edita(char *filename) {
    
    /* Limpia pantalla */
    clear();

    /* Lee archivo */
    char *map = mapFile(filename);
    if (map == NULL) {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    
    for(int i= 0; i<25; i++) {
        // Haz linea, base y offset
        char *l = hazLinea(map,i*16);
        move(i,0);
        addstr(l);
    }
    refresh();

    int c = getch();
    
    while (c != 26) {
        switch (c) {
            case KEY_LEFT:
                break;
        }
        c = getch();
    }

    if (munmap(map, fd) == -1) {
      perror("Error al desmapear");
    }
    close(fd);
    
   return 0;

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    initscr();
    raw(); 
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);   /* Para obtener F1,F2,.. */
    noecho();

    /* El archivo se da como parametro */
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Se usa %s <archivo> \n", argv[0]);
        return(-1);
    }

    edita((char *)argv[1]);

    endwin();
    
    return 0;
}`

I know that it's written in spanish, but I hope you get the idea. The problem is that I can't compile it. I've tried
gcc -o hex hex.c 
gcc -o hex hex.c -lrt

But it doesn't work. I get this:
$ gcc -o h hex.c 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccrFjiTL.o: en la función `leeChar':
hex.c:(.text+0x36a): referencia a `stdscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x377): referencia a `nodelay' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x37f): referencia a `stdscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x387): referencia a `wgetch' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x39a): referencia a `ungetch' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x3b5): referencia a `stdscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x3bd): referencia a `wgetch' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccrFjiTL.o: en la función `edita':
hex.c:(.text+0x422): referencia a `stdscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x42a): referencia a `wclear' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x475): referencia a `stdscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x487): referencia a `wmove' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x48e): referencia a `stdscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x4a2): referencia a `waddnstr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x4b3): referencia a `stdscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x4bb): referencia a `wrefresh' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x4c2): referencia a `stdscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x4ca): referencia a `wgetch' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x4dd): referencia a `stdscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x4e5): referencia a `wgetch' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccrFjiTL.o: en la función `main':
hex.c:(.text+0x543): referencia a `initscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x548): referencia a `raw' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x54f): referencia a `stdscr' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x55c): referencia a `keypad' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x561): referencia a `noecho' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: hex.c:(.text+0x5a1): referencia a `endwin' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


That's the source code I got from the teacher. I'm supposed to add more features, but I can't even get the original code, working. Can you help me, please?
Thanks.
Something like this is what the code must show

you need one of curses lib installed and build it with smth like cc $(pkg-config --cflags ncursesw) -o hex hex.c $(pkg-config --libs ncursesw)

Already got to run the code, but thanks. Maybe the PC I'm using rn at school had it already installed, but I'll consider your answer just in case :)

@MiguelSalazar Tip: char *base --> unsigned char *base to avoid sign extension issues with signed char.

Having the lib installed on your school PC doesn't help if you don't add the lib to your compilation command. Using same build commands should give different error message if the lib is not installed.

The functions with undefined references are part of the curses library, so add that library to the compiler command.
gcc -o hex hex.c gcc -o hex hex.c -lrt -lcurses


Thx. I know get the message about compiler not detecting gcc. I must install lcurses with sudo or something?

My bad. I just copied and pasted your line. It's duplicated. If I compile gcc -o hex hex.c -lrt -lcurses I gotta run it like: ./hex hex.c  , and I kinda get what I needed hehe. Thanks.

@MiguelSalazar : As you can see from the wording of the message, it is not the compiler complaining about something, but the linker.
